# CTE performance in ActionFilter Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have an ActionFilter Attribute that checks the privileges of a user. In that filter attribute i'm running a CTE

```
WITH Emp_CTE AS (
     SELECT DesignationID, Title
     FROM setupDesignations
     WHERE ReportTo ='+@PositionID+'
    UNION ALL
     SELECT d.DesignationID, d.Title
     FROM setupDesignations d
     INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.DesignationID = d.ReportTo
    )
    Select COUNT(*) from 
    ( 
    SELECT distinct SPOID from mktDoctorSPOs where SPOID IN (Select DesignationID from Emp_CTE) 
     UNION
    SELECT SPOID from mktDoctorSPOs where SPOID = '+@PositionID+'
    ) tmp
```

i'm concerned about the performance issues as it has to be executed on each request, can this be improved or is there any better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest caching the results. It would seem easy enough to populate the [ASP.NET cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and then so long as your query has vaguely decent performance, you'll only need to run it once per user.

Given that hitting the database is expensive anyway, caching the results here will help even if you have a good query.

Otherwise you might look at restructuring your database to not require the CTE, possibly a simpler structure, or an indexed view that mimics a simpler structure.

Comment: He can remove the CTE without restructuring. In general a CTE is always poor for performance.